# 文字列の特定文字を削除するプログラム

Tags: c++

すみません。どう考えて、書いても、答えが出ないので、ここで、みんなの力を借りさせていただきます。

文字列の中から特定の文字を削除するプログラムを記述しなさい。
// 変数 str から、変数 code 代入された文字を削除する事。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // 変数宣言
    char str[10] = "";
    char code = '\0';
    

    // 削除する文字列と文字を入力
    cout << "削除する対象：";
    cin >> str;
    cout << "削除する文字：";
    cin >> code;

    // 入力された文字列の中から文字を削除
    
    // 結果を出力
    cout << "削除後の文字列：" << str;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++言語には文字列として[`std::string`](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)が用意されていますが、これを使用しないのでしょうか？

Comment: Char文字列を使う課題なので、std::stringを使って行けないって先生に言われました。

Comment: 課題ならば授業や例題で関連した問題を解いていらっしゃると考えると、全く浮かばないことはないとは思います。どの程度までアルゴリズムを構築することができましたか？自身が考えた頭の中のロジックをぜひ言葉にして質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: 「std::stringを使ってはいけけない」とありますが、他にもプログラムを作成するにあたって何か前提条件 (制限等) がもしあるなら、それらを質問中に追記してください。

Comment: 自分が考えたのは　例えば　str[10]にabbabbaを代入して、削除したい文字bをcodeに代入します。繰り返し文を使って、bという文字を見つかったら、後ろの文字を今見つかったどころの配列に代入します。 例: abbabba -> ababba -> aabba -> aaba -> aaa (最後にcoutする文字)。制限は　algorithmとか　std::removeを使わないで　繰り返し文とか　if文　といった初心者が初めて　勉強するもので作ればいいと思います。(すみません。もし日本語がおかしいなら、お許しください)

Comment: [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)の "Possible implementation" の項には `std::remove` と同等の処理を行なう関数の例が載っています。

Answer (score 1):

[std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) を使う方法はどうでしょうか。

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
                :

  // 入力された文字列の中から文字を削除
  *remove(str, str+strlen(str), code) = 0;

  // 結果を出力
  cout << "削除後の文字列：" << str << endl; // endl を追加
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char str[10] = "teeeeste";
    char code = 'e';

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str); ++i){
        if(str[i] == code){
            for(int j = i; j < sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str)-1; ++j){
                str[j] = str[j+1];
            }
            --i;
        }
    }
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

指摘されたので修正しました

Comment: うーんちょっと惜しい感じ。 `[10]` 依存、かつ `e` が複数個あるときにまずいっスね。まあ後者は元質問者から仕様が出てないからこれでも許されるのかも。

Comment: 指摘されたので修正しました

Comment: 内側のループは `memmove()` で済みますね。(`strcpy()` はダメ)

Comment: #inclue<cstring>は、していないみたいなので、memmoveできない気がします